# weired python calculations

Tags: python, math

So this is my python code

```
print rating
rating = pow( rating,1/5 )
print rating
```

It outputs

```
0.0
1.0
```

My knowledge of maths tells me pow(0,anything) should be zero. What is wrong ? :/

Comment: Your knowledge of maths is missing `pow(0, 0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `1/5` will be `0`, because it's evaluated using *integer arithmetic*:

```
int/int = int
```

Therefore, the result of `pow(rating, 0)` will be `1-0`.

**What can you do?** In order to get the expected result (`float`), you can use a `float` instead of an `int` number:

```
1.0 / 5     # float / int = float
1 / 5.0     # int / float = float
1.0 / 5.0   # float / float = float
```

Comment: I'd prefer to put `from __future__ import division` at the top of the file.

Comment: This is true for python 2. For python 3, 1/5 is floating point division and is equal to 0.2.

Answer (score 2):

`1 / 5` equals `0`, and `pow(anything, 0)` is `1.0`. `1.0 / 5`, on the other hand, is approximately `0.2`, as are `1 / 5.0` and `1.0 / 5.0`. Because, as the tutorial [mentioned](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#numbers), a mathematical operation with two integral operands has an integral result.

Comment: You could add that 1/5 uses integer arithmetic and thus won't return a float, as you might expect.

Comment: I could. Or I could assume that [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#numbers) has already been consulted.

Answer (score 2):

`1/5` is truncated to `0` (since you are using Python2)

`pow(0, 0)` returns `1` by convention. You should check math.stackexchange if you need to understand the reasons.